# How to make sure the SearchBar Textfield is empty

Tags: swift, searchbar

I have a SearchBar when i press the cancel button i have it set so that the textfield should have no text and all of my collection view cell's show

When the cancel button is tapped while there is still text in the TextField my collection view shows no cells until i go back into the search bar and press the delete button "X"

Would appreciate some help Thanks

Here is the code

```
        print(" search button pressed")

        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .black
        searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .white
        searchBar.placeholder = "search for a contact"

        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white

    } else {

        print(" cancel button pressed")

        searchBar.searchTextField.text? = ""

        navigationItem.titleView = nil

        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled  = true
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .purple

        collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: so whats going on right now  ?

Comment: `searchBar.searchTextField.text? = ""` you are setting this text to empty and reloading collectionView ... what issues you are facing ?\

Comment: when i use the SearchTextField it filters everything like i want it too, but if i leave any text in the textField and press the Cancel button no cells will show

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assigning `nil` to `searchBar.searchTextField.text`? Maybe that can make a difference.

Comment: yes i tried that but get the same error any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried doing `searchBar.searchTextField.text.removeAll()`?

Comment: Yes i have tried that too i get the same result, once i press the cancel button all cells disappear until i go back in the textField and press the Delete button "X" or press the back space button. i can't see what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

here's how I would check if I've done my implementation properly. Make sure I'm calling necessary delegate methods for  `UISearchBarDelegate` and handle filter there.

```
extension MyViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        if (searchBar.text?.count)! > 0 {
            searchHandler(searchText: searchBar.text!)
        }
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        filteredValues?.removeAll() // this removes any previous array items
        filteredValues = listValues // this assigns your listValues to filteredValues
        collectionView?.reloadData() // this reloads your collectionView
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if (searchBar.text?.count)! > 0 {
            searchHandler(searchText: searchBar.text!)
        }
        return true
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {}

    func  searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchHandler(searchText: searchText)
    }

    fileprivate func searchHandler(searchText: String) {
      //implement your filtering here
    }
}
```

Again, there are different ways you can implement your search filtering and assign your filtered values to the collectionView data source.

Hope this helps. Thanks